# Could not ping to registered host service from terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp

A very good day to all of you .

Yesterday i registered with byethost11.com and registered for free hosting service .
The registration was done successfully and they provided me with the hostname , username , password .

Now my question is that ,

I could not able to connect to them using ssh option from my terminal .
(I could able to connect to it using FileZilla , winscp )
I am usiing Ubuntu 12 version .

Please let me know how can i connect to them ??

( I dont want to use Filezill , winscp  for this purpose )

Thank you for reading .

Comment: Did you try telnetting the host at port 22?

Answer (score 0):

From past experience using hosting services, on the cheaper deals an SSH service is not provided. I have looked over the specifications for your hosting package [here](http://byethost.com/index.php/free-hosting), and it does not promote that service is supported.

Have you had any communications from your provider to suggest this is provided?